# Using FTDI D2xx and Thorlabs APT communication protocol results in delays on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, delay, ftdi, d2xx

I am trying to communicate with the Thorlabs TDC001 controllers (apt - dc servo controller) by using the FTDI D2xx driver on Linux. However, when I send writing commands, large delays occur (1-2 seconds) until the command is actually executed on TDC001.
In particular, this can be observed when the connected linear stage is moving and a new position command is sent. It takes 1-2 seconds until the stage actually changes its direction. Also, if I request DCSTATUSUPDATE (which gives position and velocity) and then read out the queue of FTDI, I do not get the right data. Only if I wait 1 second between requesting and reading, I get the (correct) data, but for the past. I added the C++ code for this case.
I need live-data and faster execution of writing commands for closed-loop control.

I'm not sure if the problem is on the side of Thorlabs or FTDI. Everything works, except for the large delays. There are other commands, e.g. MOVE_STOP, which respond immediately. Also, if I send a new position command right after finishing homing, it is executed immediately.
Whenever I ask for FT_GetStatus, there is nothing else in the Tx or Rx queue except the 20 bytes in Rx for DCSTATUSUPDATE.

The references for D2XX and APT communication protocol can be found here:

[FTDI Programmer's Guide](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf)

[Thorlabs APT Communication Protocol](https://www.thorlabs.com/software/apt/APT_Communications_Protocol_Rev_15.pdf)

The initialization function:

```
bool CommunicationFunctions::initializeKeyHandle(string serialnumber){
  //INITIALIZATION//
  /*
   * This function initializes the TDC motor controller and finds its corresponding keyhandle.
   */
  keyHandle = NULL;

  // To open the device, the vendor and product ID must be set correctly
  ftStatus = FT_SetVIDPID(0x403,0xfaf0);
  }

  //Open device:
  const char* tmp = serialnumber.c_str();
  int numAttempts=0;
  while (keyHandle ==0){
    ftStatus = FT_OpenEx(const_cast<char*>(tmp),FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER, &keyHandle);
    if (numAttempts++>20){
      cerr << "Device Could Not Be Opened";
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Set baud rate to 115200
  ftStatus = FT_SetBaudRate(keyHandle,115200);

  // 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity
  ftStatus = FT_SetDataCharacteristics(keyHandle, FT_BITS_8, FT_STOP_BITS_1, FT_PARITY_NONE);

  // Pre purge dwell 50ms.
  usleep(50);

  // Purge the device.
  ftStatus = FT_Purge(keyHandle, FT_PURGE_RX | FT_PURGE_TX);

  // Post purge dwell 50ms.
  usleep(50);

  // Reset device.
  ftStatus = FT_ResetDevice(keyHandle);

  // Set flow control to RTS/CTS.
  ftStatus = FT_SetFlowControl(keyHandle, FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS, 0, 0);

  // Set RTS.
  ftStatus = FT_SetRts(keyHandle);

  return true;
}
```

How I read out my data:

```
bool CommunicationFunctions::read_tdc(int32_t* position, uint16_t* velocity){    
  uint8_t *RxBuffer = new uint8_t[256]();
  DWORD RxBytes;
  DWORD BytesReceived = 0;

  // Manually request status update:
  uint8_t req_statusupdate[6] = {0x90,0x04,0x01,0x00,0x50,0x01};
  ftStatus = FT_Write(keyHandle, req_statusupdate, (DWORD)6, &written);
  if(ftStatus != FT_OK){
    cerr << "Command could not be transmitted: Request status update" << endl;
    return false;
  }

//  sleep(1); //**this sleep() would lead to right result, but I don't want this delay**

  // Get number of bytes in queue of TDC001
  FT_GetQueueStatus(keyHandle,&RxBytes);

  // Check if there are bytes in queue before reading them, otherwise do
  // not read anything in
  if(RxBytes>0){
    ftStatus=FT_Read(keyHandle,RxBuffer,RxBytes,&BytesReceived);
    if(ftStatus != FT_OK){
      cerr << "Read device failed!" << endl;
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Check if enough bytes are received, i.e. if signal is right
  if(!(BytesReceived >= 6)){
    cerr << "Error in bytes received" << endl;
    return false;
  }

  // Look for correct message in RxBuffer and read out velocity and position
  getPosVel(position,velocity,RxBuffer);

  // Delete receive buffer
  delete[] RxBuffer;
  RxBuffer = NULL;

  return true;
}
```

If I use read_tdc function after homing and during movement to absolute position, I just get "Homing completed" message in the first attempt. When I try read_tdc again, I get an old value (probably the one from before). I don't understand what happens here. Why does this old data even remain in the queue (latency is 10 ms). Can anybody help me to get faster responses and reactions?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to do some driver debugging..

Comment: I think putting a logic analyzer on the UART lines would be a lot easier than driver debugging, and should prove whether the latency comes from the target device or the FTDI.  Note that the WIndows FTDI VCP drivers have quite a few settings to play with in the device properties dialog in device manager, and several of those affect latency.  Can't remember if there's an API to control those when using D2XX mode, but if there is one, it should work on the Linux D2XX as well.